# Why does "grep -r" not accept "*"?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm using a lot `grep -r [text]` command to recursively locate a text, even bundled in a zipped file. However I found out it does not work with "*" expression:

```
$ grep -r "*.cert"

[nothing]

$ grep -r "ca.cert"

[entries found]
```

Escaping the character does not help either. Why is that?

Comment: Just try `grep -r '.cert$'`. This will give you all entries that end with `.cert`

Comment: @sisanared Your suggestion would only find the pattern at the end of a line. If the file name is in some continuous text though the pattern should end with a word boundary: `'.*\.cert\>'`. In fact, it should exclude whitespace from the file name, or it would find the whole line before ".cert". Something along `'[^[:space:]]*\.cert\>'` (untested). Assuming file names cannot contain whitespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are somehow confusing globs with regular expressions. In `grep`, the expression you are searching for is a regex, so you have to follow its rules.

When globbing, `*` expands to any character.

When using regular expressions, `*` is a quantifier of how many times the thing in its left can appear. But you do not specify anything to the left of it!

Just use `.` to mean any character:

```
grep -r ".*\.cert"
#        ^
```

See also how I am escaping the second dot, so it is a literal dot and not the metacharacter.

Comment: You may also want to escape the literal dot, by the same logic. I assume that the files are named `xy.cert` etc. Your suggestion: yes. (Without the escape the pattern would find `xyzcert` which is probably not intended.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider not really, since I use it to match any character. But I see your point, maybe my answer would be better with something like `'.*\.cert'` to match whatever followed by `.cert`.

Comment: In fact, if the grep is looking for file names and one does not want to find e.g. `some.certmanual.doc` one should make the end a word boundary: `'.*\.cert\>'`

Comment: Finally, if we assume continuous text (and not some `ls` output, one file per line), we must guard against whitespace. See my comment to the question above.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider agreed, although it can get trick if the file contains spaces like `"my file.cert"`.

Comment: Note that if `grep` reported this use of the `*` operator as an error rather than "helpfully" treating it as a literal characters, the problem would be much easier to solve.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the dot at the beginning of the regularexpression. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

To handle truly arbitrary file names in *nix is unexpectedly difficult, bordering on the impossible. To get an impression: [This](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) and [this](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) by the same author.

So the requirement is to find all files of the form "xy.cert", but *only* those. We don't want to find "xycert" or "xy.certificate".

If we can assume file names which do not have a space after the ".cert" (for example, "xy.cert my butt", which is a legal file name in modern file systems), we  can simply use `'\.cert\>'`. This finds any occurrence of ".cert" with white space after it, or at EOF. `\>` denotes the end of a word, so that "xy.certificate" is no match.

If finding files named ".cert" is not desired, we should say `'[^[:space:]]+\.cert\>'`, similar to in my comment. (I changed the asterisk to a plus in order to enforce at least one non-whitespace in the file name before the dot.) I must use `egrep` for that pattern.

Comment: TL;DR: in a stream or text, to find filenames whose extension is `cert`, do use `'\.cert\>'`.

Comment: @fedorqui Correct ;-). But, thinking of it, that may not be desired -- do we want to find a file named ".cert"?

Comment: If you can avoid using `egrep`, just escape the `+`: `'[^[:space:]]\+\.cert\>'`.